# Bootstrap datetimepicker disable minutes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I am using v4 from https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker. Now I am trying to disable the minutes-selector on time-selection. I know I could use:

```
$(this).datetimepicker({
  format: 'HH'
});
```

But with this code, minutes aren't shown at all. I would like to show minutes in the selector, but disable it. Any chance to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried using `dp.show` and `dp.change` events to handle it.

In the show event minutes element are disabled in order to avoid minutes changing and the hour part is taken and followed by `:00`.

Code:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    format: 'HH:mm'
}).on('dp.show', function () {
    $('a.btn[data-action="incrementMinutes"], a.btn[data-action="decrementMinutes"]').removeAttr('data-action').attr('disabled', true);
    $('span.timepicker-minute[data-action="showMinutes"]').removeAttr('data-action').attr('disabled', true).text('00');
}).on('dp.change', function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val().split(':')[0]+':00')
    $('span.timepicker-minute').text('00')
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mfjvnh9a/

Answer (score 18):

I've found a solution. Use this time-format:

```
format: 'HH:00'
```

Comment: This works WAY better for me than the accepted answer...!!

Answer (score 5):

set plugin option `'minView' => 1`

Comment: Useful answer for those who don't want to show minutes form at all. This is documentation link https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#min-view-mode for javascript syntax.

Comment: thnku very much for your answer

Comment: it works!. 
jq("#date").datetimepicker({
   minView:1,
});

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).datetimepicker({ steps: 60 });
```

If you do this when you loose focus the plugin adjusts your time to :00 for your minutes (if you happen to type the date).