# Disable minutes selection in Bootstrap Datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I wan't datetimepicker to show only rounded hours and disable minutes selection. So user will be able to pick only hours, like 02:00. However I can't achieve this simple task. Here is my code (in a Laravel view):

```
$("#date_from").datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:00',
    startDate: "{{date('Y-m-d')}}",
    minuteStepping: 60,
    autoclose: true }).on('hide', function(e) {
        $("#date_to").datetimepicker(
            "setStartDate", new Date($('#date_from').val())
         )....
```

I've tried `steps: 60`, `stepping:60`, `minView: 1` and others.
Still I'm getting this [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap datetimepicker disable minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487817/bootstrap-datetimepicker-disable-minutes)

Comment: Well, there is not only one solution. And the solution there which was accepted was a bit ugly looking. The solution here is way better and clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one example for you, i think it will help you.

jsfiddle.net/tmk0293z/7/

There is changedate event bind with a function and changes the another startdate of other field.

Thanks,
Nishit Zinzuvadiya

Here is the actual code
(HTML):

```
<div class="input-append date form_datetime" id="first">
<input type="text" value="" readonly>
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="input-append date form_datetime" id="second">
    <input type="text" value="" readonly>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
<span id="selected"></span>
```

JS:

```
 $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
   format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
   minView:1,
   autoclose:true
 });

 $("#first").datetimepicker().on("changeDate", function(e){     
  var first = new Date(e.date.setMinutes(0));
        first.setHours(first.getHours()+first.getTimezoneOffset()/60); //timezone correction

  $("#second").datetimepicker('setStartDate', first); 

  //other = $("#first").find("input").val(); 
  //$("#second").datetimepicker('setStartDate', other); //works also

 });
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! please accept the changes. I've attached your code to your post

Comment: in my case `format` has to be `format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:00'`

Answer (score 0):

see the option viewMode and format
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/

Answer (score 0):

try using **step: 60**  not **steps**
please check this link also :[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489684/jquery-timepicker-interval)