# Show only the date and hour of a datetime input in ASP.NET Core View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime

I am writing a simple project in ASP.NET Core. I want a user to only set the date and hour of a datetime input control, but not the minutes. I have tried, but the minutes part is always visible and pickable! Any solution to hide or disable it is welcome.

Here is the `DateTime` property in the ViewModel:

```cs
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false, 
 DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH}")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

And the corresponding `input` tag in the View:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" asp-for="StartDate" name="StartDate" id="StartDate" data-date-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH}" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH}" class="form-control" />
```

[image: datetime field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any solution to not show minute part or disable it is acceptable.

If you are using browser default datepicker widget as the screenshot you shared, which seems not enable us to customize and disable `minute` picker part within that default datepicker widget.

If possible, you can try to use some jQuery datepicker widget to achieving the requirement, like below.

```
<div class="input-append date form_datetime">
    <input type="text" asp-for="StartDate" id="StartDate" class="form-control" readonly />
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

Required references and js code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
<script src="https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
        format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:00",
        minView:1,
        autoclose:true
        });
    })
</script>
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47978234/6751634) discussed about disabling minutes selection in Bootstrap Datetimepicker, you can refer to it.

Comment: unfortunately this javascript not run! even i put its code in my project

Comment: no error, it seems javascript not run because after click noting is appeared in screen, i must mention that i use jquery.js in view